# Is there any file/directory permission effect if change uid or gid on Linux?

Tags: permissions, users, group, uid, gid

If group and user's settings are

- group name: group1
- gid: 2000
- user name: user1
- uid: 2000

Some directory's permission is

- Directory: /application
- Owner: user1
- Group: group1

When change the gid and uid to `2001`, is there any permission issue for the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filesystem stores the UID and GID of the owner, not the name, so if you change your UID to `2001` you will no longer be owner of that directory, owner will still be the (now non-existing) user with UID `2000`.

Comment: So if I change the directory's permission again(with user and group names after their ids have been changed), is it good while the directory is under using by system process?